# Why is theano running so slow?

Tags: theano

I'm new to Theano and trying out some examples.

```
import numpy
import theano.tensor as T
from theano import function
import datetime
print datetime.datetime.now()
x = T.dscalar('x')
y = T.dscalar('y')
z = x + y
f = function([x, y], z)
print f(2, 3)
print numpy.allclose(f(16.3, 12.1), 28.4)
print datetime.datetime.now()
```

And it took 15 minutes to run this. I'm using a 2GB ram, and there aren't many processes running simultaneously.

Comment: Can you break it down to see which step is taking the time? Probably `f = function(...)`, where compilation happens, but would be good to make sure.

Comment: I ran the same piece of code and it ran under a second. Have you updated the version of NumPy & Theano on your machine ?

Comment: The f = function([x, y], z) takes up more that 95% of the time, everything else runs smooth

Answer (score 4):

Check the Theano Flags first.

If you didnt run with : **THEANO_FLAGS=mode=FAST_RUN** or ran with not the default flag or if you changed the .theanorc , it might take some time.

--

However, read here:

http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/using_gpu.html

You can also see more about Theano Flags here:

http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html

Since you must be running from an IDE, you will have to edit the ***.theanorc***

As described on the Theano Link above:

"
It defaults to $HOME/.theanorc. On Windows, it defaults to $HOME/.theanorc:$HOME/.theanorc.txt to make Windows users’ life easier.
"

The exact flag is this :

**config.mode**

String value: 'Mode', 'ProfileMode' (deprecated), 'DebugMode', 'FAST_RUN', 'FAST_COMPILE'

In case this doesnt help, be sure to ***update Theano to bleeding edge*** and ***edit your question with the theanorc settings***!

***pip install --upgrade  --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git***

---

*You can also use OpenMP to use extra Threads/cores :*

**THEANO_FLAGS=mode=FAST_RUN THEANO_FLAGS='openmp=True' OMP_NUM_THREADS=4** python x.py