# slow performance of neupy

Tags: python-3.x, neupy

I have Python3.6.4 and neupy 0.6.4. I have hone thru toturial on neupy page http://neupy.com/2015/07/04/boston_house_prices_dataset.html#boston-house-price, times that was shown on page were much shorter then times printed on my PC.

Total execution time on toturial page: 51ms+38ms+146ms+38ms+41ms = **314ms**

My execution time: **8min**

Why toturial time and my time are so different and how can I speed up execution?

Comment: There are just too many factors to really know. Unless you have a beast of a machine, chances are the editors had a better machine than you. To me, that would be the biggest contributing factor, but again, there are too many factors to really know

Comment: I run this code on the mac and I have the same results. My code runs around 50ms per epoch (for 100 epochs). My mac has 2.2 GHz Intel Core i7, 4 cores and 16GB RAM.

Comment: Can you share your Theano version? Also, do you get some strange warnings from Theano? And, what OS do you use?

Comment: NeuPy uses Theano and sometimes people experience similar issues. You can try to upgrade Theano and set up a few environment flags. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37781259/2759088